# How to add caching to the php script?

Tags: php, html, api

there is a script (I have such on site 8)

```
<?php

    $map = function($array, $from, $to){
        $result = [];
        if(!empty($array) && is_array($array)){
            foreach ($array as $element) {
                $key = $element[$from]?:null;
                $value = $element[$to]?:null;
                if($key && $value){
                    $result[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    };

   $airlines = $map(json_decode(file_get_contents('http://aviaciya.com/json/airlines.json'), true), 'iata', 'name');
$cit=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://avia-avia.ru/json/cities.json")); $cities=array(); foreach($cit as $val) { if(property_exists($val->name_translations,"ru")) $cities[$val->code]=$val->name_translations->ru;}

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=MOW&destination=AER&limit=30&token=**************");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: *************"));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $products=json_decode($response,true);
    $replace_value = function($key, $val) use ($cities, $airlines){
        $response = $val;
        switch($key){case 'destination':
                $response = $cities[$val];break;
                case 'origin':
                $response = $cities[$val];break;
            case 'airline':
                $response = $airlines[$val];
                break;
        }
        return $response;
    }

    ?>








    <div id="kurorty" class="container-fluid">

     <div class="table-responsive"><h5>Авиабилеты Москва Адлер</h5><table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;"> Пункт отправления</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Пункт назначения </th>
            <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;"> Авиакомпания</th> <th style="text-align: center;">Цена, р.</th> <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;">Дата вылета</th>
    <th class="mob" style="text-align: center;">Обратная дата</th>
    <th> </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>    <tbody>
    <?php
    if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])) {
    foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $destination => $row) {
    if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}/i', $key)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp; <?php echo Москва ;?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp; <?= $replace_value('destination',$key) ? $replace_value('destination', $key) : "<b>" .'Обновл.'. "</b>"; ?>&nbsp; </td>

         <td class="mob"><img height="50" alt="" width="120" src="http://pics.avs.io/180/70/<?= $row['airline']?>.png" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $replace_value('price', $row['price']); ?>&nbsp;  RUB &nbsp; </td> 
    <td class="mob"><?php echo $replace_value('departure_at', substr($row['departure_at'], 0, 10)); ?></td>
    <td class="mob"><?php echo $replace_value('return_at', substr($row['return_at'], 0, 10)); ?></td>
          <td><a rel="nofollow" role="button" alt="авиабилеты Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?>" title="авиабилеты Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?>" href="https://bilety.avia-avia.ru/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=<?=$key?>&depart_date=<?=substr($row['departure_at'], 0, 10)?>&return_date=<?=substr($row['return_at'], 0, 10)?>&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true">Поиск</a></td></tr>
    <?php
    }
    }
    }
    }
    ?>  </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

In subsequent scripts, I do not use this line anymore

```
$airlines = $map(json_decode(file_get_contents('http://aviaciya.com/json/airlines.json'), true), 'iata', 'name');
$cit=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://avia-avia.ru/json/cities.json")); $cities=array(); foreach($cit as $val) { if(property_exists($val->name_translations,"ru")) $cities[$val->code]=$val->name_translations->ru;}
```

That's what a good person wrote to me:

> "The script is very simple, you take json and save it, there are a
>   couple of lines for correcting your script, and in your code only the
>   URL will need to be changed." The idea is that you need to save $
>   products to a file and read from this file. "

Everything is so simple, only for me it's a rattling forest." Please help, my hands are falling already.

Thank you very much in advance for your help, with great respect.

Comment: If you don't have to use those two lines, your have to keep the two variables called $airlines et $ cities, as the Good Samaritan said.
You can... store these in a session variable if you had to use in other scripts instead of in a file.

Comment: Caching in this manner of scripts means, disable the file_get_contents with a remote target. Download the file (with php) to your localhost and read the content from there.

Additionaly you can check the filemtime to redownload the file again, so this will be the easy caching functionality.

Comment: @rebru Can you fix the script to happen like you said "simple caching" and issue a response? I will be very grateful to you, I did not write the site, I bought it ready, and here such an ambush. With best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voilà, append this into the head of your script

```
/**
 * Function to get cacheFile
 * @param $srcfile
 * @return string
 */
function cacheFile($srcfile)
{
    /* Defintions */
    /**
     * string Cachepath is the path to your www-user writeable directory, this can be relative or absolute
     */
    $cachePath = './';


    /**
     * array srcfiles, key is Identifier and value is the full link to the json file
     */
    $srcfiles = [
        'airline' => 'http://aviaciya.com/json/airlines.json',
        'cities' => 'http://avia-avia.ru/json/cities.json'
    ];


    /**
     * Autogenerated from cachePath and srcfiles
     */
    $cacheFile = $cachePath.end(explode("/", $srcfiles[$srcfile]));


    /**
     * int Time in seconds for cache
     */
    $cachingTime = 600;


    /**
     * @param $cacheFile
     * @param $url
     */
    $downloader = function($cacheFile, $url) {
        file_put_contents($cacheFile,file_get_contents($url));
    };

    /* CreateCache File if it doesnt exists */
    if(!file_exists($cacheFile) || time() - filemtime($cacheFile) > $cachingTime) {
        $downloader($cacheFile, $srcfiles[$srcfile]);
    }

    return $cacheFile;
}
```

Then you can call this loader instead of giving the fqdn to the file_get_contents function, like this ...

```
$airlines = map(json_decode(file_get_contents(cacheFile('airline')), true), 'iata', 'name');
$cit=json_decode(file_get_contents(cacheFile('cities'))); $cities=array(); foreach($cit as $val) { if(property_exists($val->name_translations,"ru")) $cities[$val->code]=$val->name_translations->ru;}
```

## Update

- Better downloader function (only cacheFile and URL as parameters)
- file existence and filemtimecheck in once